# distinguishing participial adjectives from non participial adjectives

Tags: participial-adjectives

So far as I know, there's no way to know what verbs can become participial adjectives and what verbs cannot. But would someone PLEASE show me that I'm wrong! :) Thank you :)
P.S.

Comment: I don't think you **are** wrong. There are some heuristics - for example, intransitive past participles tend not to form adjectives unless they refer to a change of state (eg _fallen_, but not _slept_). But you can't rely on this.

Comment: I'm confused by the title of your question. Are you really asking how to distinguish participial adjectives from non-participial adjectives, or which verbs have participial adjective forms and which don't? there is a difference.

Comment: Ooops! Thanks BillJ for catching that! Please disregard the title of my question. I was originally just going to say "participial adjectives" but Stack wouldn't accept just that, saying it didn't meet the standards, so I added words to the title sorta haphazardly!

Comment: You might want to give us some examples of what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Lambie ... now why didn't I think of this?! An example would be a good idea. And, while thinking of examples, I came up with a possible answer. How's this? Verbs that can become participial adjectives show action by the subject on the object of the verb. Two examples: 

1. It interests me. (v.) --> I'm interested. (adj.) & It's interesting. (adj.)
2. He convinced me. (v.) --> I'm convinced. (adj.) & It's convincing. (adj.)

I could very well be overlooking something. And if this is a grammar rule, then there must be exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no clear cut rule; it is simply a matter of historical accident which verbs generate adjectives from their participles. Moreover, some sources describe adjectives that end in -ed or -ing but    do not correspond to the participle of any verb as "participle adjectives". For example [an article from Your Dictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html)  says:

> [S]ome participial adjectives are derived from verbs, while others simply look like verb forms because of their -ed or -ing endings.

[This page from *Internet Grammar*](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/particip.htm) makes  similar claim. Examples given include "renowned" and "talented".

But since participial adjectives do not function in any different way from other adjectives, there is no real need to know which adjectives are participial adjectives, just to know which words can function as adjectives.  Indeed the category of participial adjectives  serves little purpose in my view.

Comment: Particular care is needed in certain cases. For example, in the NP "a sleeping child", the word "sleeping" modifies "child" but it is a verb, not an adjective

Comment: "there is no real need to know which adjectives are participial adjectives, just to know which words can function as adjectives" 
-good stuff here :) tasty food for thought :) Thanks David :)

Comment: How can a verb modify a noun? By virtue of the ing or ed ending, verbs can become adjectives. Let sleeping dogs lie.

Comment: Of course VPs can modify nouns. In my example "sleeping" fails all the tests for adjectivehood.

Comment: @Lambie  Did my answer raise the question of whether or how participles can be used to modify nouns? By referring to "participle  adjectives" I thought that was clear.

Comment: @BillJ First you say a sleeping child is an NP; then, you say VPs can modify nouns. Please give me the noun that "a sleeping child" modifies.